# Can SQL server 2012 Service Pack 2 be applied to an Express Edition instance?

Tags: sql-server, service-pack, sql-server-express, sql-server-2012

I need to upgrade an instance of SQL Server 2012 Express Edition (SP1) to Service Pack 2.

Can the standard Service Pack 2 package be applied to an Express Edition instance, or do I need to run the installer for Express Edition with SP2 and upgrade the instance?

---

Ordinarily I would just download the SP2 package and run it, and if it complains about an edition mismatch I'd download the new Express Edition installer and run that. But this is a remote server with low bandwidth, and downloading hundreds of MBs is a real pain. Also, I can't seem to find documentation about applying service packs to Express instances...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. SQL Service packs cover all editions, including express editions